# grails - command not found install-templates

Tags: grails, web.xml

"grails run-app" is functioning normally,

But "grails install-templates" did not run.

My version of Grills is 3.3.8.

[image]

( The purpose of this is to create web.xml. )

thanks!

Comment: Since Grails 3.x uses Spring Boot, there is no web.xml (afaik).

Answer (score 0):

`install-templates` script is part of [Grails scaffolding plugin](https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/scaffolding). Make sure that you have it in your project dependencies.